# How to find current Doctrine migration version with Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I want to get the current doctrine migration version currently in use in database using Doctrine classes. I know I can just query `SELECT version FROM doctrine_migration_versions ORDER BY version DESC LIMIT 1` but I cannot find any official function from Doctrine classes. Is there such?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to retrieve the current version you can launch this command

```
symfony console doctrine:migrations:current
```

If you want to retrieve the version from your source code you can do the following (extract from `vendor/doctrine/migrations/lib/Doctrine/Migrations/Tools/Console/Command/CurrentCommand.php`).

Inject the `doctrine.migrations.dependency_factory` service in one of yours service.

```
$aliasResolver = $this->dependencyFactory->getVersionAliasResolver();

$version = $aliasResolver->resolveVersionAlias('current');
```

`$version` will print you `Version20210930102127` for example